# Windows 10 browser upload - wrong mimetype

Tags: python, angularjs, excel, windows, file-upload

I got a problem with uploading xls and doc files via webbrowser to my python application.

When using `Win 10 Home 10.0.14393` I receive `application/octet-stream` mimetype in my backend for xls files. But when using `Win 10 Home 10.0.15063` everyting works fine and mimetype is `application/vnd.ms-excel`. It fails on Chrome and Firefox (didn't test other browsers)

Does anyone nows what may cause the problem? Is there any way to fix it?

In the FE I am using `ng-file-upload` for file upload handling.

In the backend `Python 3.6` and `Ubuntu 16.04`

Comment: You should never trust content-type anyway, its a hint at best. See if the filename extension (also obviously untrustworthy) looks good then perform additional checks as needed.

Comment: So what should I do? Use for example python-magic to guess mimetype?